# Selection Sort in C using an Array of Struct, error: "lvalue required..."

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, variable-assignment

Trying to sort an array of Structs. Struct is TextArt defined below

```
typedef struct  //struct that holds ASCII art
{
    char artistName[80];    //name of artist
    char asciiArt[20][80];  //actual ascii art line by line
    int rating;             //rating of art
}TextArt;
```

I don't think the struct has anything to do with this though. I get the compiler error

error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment when trying to assign one struct to another(seen below)

```
temp = asciiArt+pos_min;
asciiArt+pos_min = asciiArt+i;  //error here
asciiArt+i = *temp;  //error also here
```

Call to function

```
selectionSort(artPtr, artArrSize);
```

and full selection sort function. Is there something I'm not understanding about assigning structs in C using =? I thought it was either this or my passing of the TextArt array was somehow wrong. Please enlighten me and thank you.

```
void selectionSort(TextArt *asciiArt, int size)
{
    //pos_min is short for position of min
    int pos_min;
    TextArt *temp;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    for (i=0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        pos_min = i;//set pos_min to the current index of array

        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if ((strncmp((asciiArt+i)->artistName, (asciiArt+j)->artistName)) < 0)
            {
                pos_min = j; //pos_min will keep track of the index that min is in, this is needed when a swap happens
            }
        }

    //if pos_min no longer equals i than a smaller value must have been found, so a swap must occur
            if (pos_min != i)
            {
                printf("copying...\n");
                temp = asciiArt+pos_min;
                asciiArt+pos_min = asciiArt+i;
                asciiArt+i = *temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct way to swap the two structs would be:

```
if (pos_min != i)
{
    printf("copying...\n");
    const TextArt temp = asciiArt[pos_min]; //equivalent to: *(asciiArt + pos_min)
    asciiArt[pos_min] = asciiArt[i];
    asciiArt[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Tried this code and it's just totally ignored, "copying..." does not even display.

Comment: If this part of the code was never reached then where is the problem? At a glance the sorting seems correct, only `for (j = i + 1` should be changed.

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I use memcpy, "copying..." is printed, with this code no output. Nothing else in the loop besides printf, no output.

Comment: Your code has errors, enable compilers warnings and try to compile.

Comment: got it.... there was a stray character from copying/pasting messing the code up. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy `structs` by assigning one pointer to the other. This way you are not creating two copies instead you are pointing both the pointers to the same address. You need to use `memcpy` instead. This is wrong:

```
temp = asciiArt+pos_min;
```

instead, use:

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

Comment: Thank you. God that was a big headache :)

Comment: Why complicate with memcpy if you can assing a temporary struct. Its better faster and less error prone.

Comment: @self can you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: You can assign structs; you just need to copy whole structs: `TextArt temp = asciiArt[min]; asciiArt[min] = asciiArt[i]; asciiArt[i] = temp;` works fine.